# JTextField to Integer Empty String Error

Tags: jtextfield, string

I have a program that is supposed to simulate an ATM Machine using GUIs. Since I only had programming experience of a week, I knew that I will be having a lot of errors and it did. This is where my problem started.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WithdrawClass implements ActionListener
{
private JTextField AmountField;
private JFrame WithdrawFrame;
private int AmountWithdrawn = 0;
private String NOW;

public void WithdrawClass()
{
    WithdrawFrame = new JFrame("Withdraw");

    JPanel TextPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel BTPanel   = new JPanel();
    JPanel UniterPanel = new JPanel();

    JLabel Texts = new JLabel("Please Enter Desired Amount: ");

    AmountField = new JTextField(20);

    JButton SubmitBT = new JButton("Enter");
    SubmitBT.addActionListener(this);

    TextPanel.add(Texts);
    TextPanel.add(AmountField);
    BTPanel.add(SubmitBT);
    UniterPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    UniterPanel.add(TextPanel);
    UniterPanel.add(BTPanel);

    WithdrawFrame.setContentPane(UniterPanel);
    WithdrawFrame.setSize(360,180);
    WithdrawFrame.pack();
    WithdrawFrame.show();
    WithdrawFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    WithdrawFrame.setResizable(false);

    NOW = AmountField.getText();
    AmountWithdrawn = Integer.parseInt(NOW);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{        
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enter"))
    {
        WithdrawFrame.hide();
        WithdrawCore Goer = new WithdrawCore();
        Goer.WithdrawCore(AmountWithdrawn);
    }
}
}
```

When I try to compile the whole thing, it has no syntax errors but when I try to run it, it had an Exception. It said that it had an empty string error around

```
AmountWithdrawn = Integer.parseInt(NOW);
```

and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I mostly tried JFormattedTextField but it didn't work. I would really appreciate it if someone can provide me with a solution.

**EDIT**

It wasn't an Empty String anymore. It was a NumberFormatException. Still the same line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
   AmountWithdrawn = Integer.parseInt(NOW);
}catch(Exception ex){
   //show a message that the input is wrong
}
```

this will solve the problem